# What's the appropriate response to the "door knock" when you are in a fitting room?

Tags: speech

I'm an international student and I have had this question for a long time:

When I'm trying on clothes in a store fitting room, the store employee sometimes knocks on the door to see if the fitting room is occupied.

How should I response to that?

Also, is there another way to refer to the people who works in the store other than"*store employee*"?

Comment: Generally speaking, a useful answer is "Yes?", with a strong question intonation. That shows the room is occupied, and probly the gender of the occupier, which is likely all the information that's needed. If they have a question, they can ask it.

Comment: It's a good idea to _always_ use "Yes?" to any knock on any door. Just so you do not mix them up and say "enter!" at the wrong moment...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about courtesy, not English.

Comment: Sorry if my post is at the wrong place. I just discovered this website and found it to be very helpful for English learner like myself.

Comment: "Someone's in here." <- what I typically say in such a situation (although it only very rarely occurs).

Answer (score 2):

What first comes to mind is "Yes?" or "Someone's in here."

Other terms for "store employee" are "[store clerk](http://www.ehow.com/about_5289428_store-clerk-job-description.html)," "[salesclerk](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=store+clerk%2C%2Csalesclerk&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstore%20clerk%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csalesclerk%3B%2Cc0)," or simply "[clerk](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/clerk)."

Comment: Not sure why this answer got a downvote (it seems perfectly adequate to me) so I tossed it an upvote to even it out.

Answer (score 2):

*Store Associate* is fine, to use when referring to the staffer assisting you with your purchase in a store.

*Occupied!* is also usable when indicating that your stall is occupied. Also applicable in restroom stalls.

Answer (score 0):

A store employee or a *shop assistant*

You can answer, "Yes?  this room is taken or busy".

Answer (score 0):

Or you could say, in a friendly way, something like, 'hi, just in here at the moment'.

In fact, you can say anything that lets them know you are there, and is also friendly.

Also, in terms of store employee/shop assistant etc., all are good; however, don't address someone as 'shop assistant' - aka don't say 'hello shop assistant, I wondered if you know where the trouser section is', just say 'hi, I wondered if you know where the trouser section is'.

Yeah.